# pass in a ternary operation in php?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

```
$foo = false;

$foo ? include 'myfile.php' : ;
```

doesn't work, what should i wrote as to avoid any instructions process in a ternary operation ?

equivalent to 'pass' in Python.

Comment: Just use the if function...

Comment: that's what I said to my boss.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to build a ternary operator without an else!

The only thing you could do is letting it empty:

```
$foo ? include 'myfile.php' : '';
```

But as Blaatpraat mentioned, it would be much more appropriate to use a simple IF statement

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
$foo and include 'myfile.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a quick and dirty &&:

```
$foo && include 'myfile.php';
```

But it would be much clearer to have a simple if statement:

```
if( $foo ) { include 'myfile.php'; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace this: `$foo ? include 'myfile.php' : ;` with this:

```
$included = $foo ? include 'myfile.php' : '';
```

Comment: Maybe because it is a less informative copy of an answer posted an hour before?